# Angular2+ shared validation between two input fields

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an interesting task (I think). I need to have an input field share validation. The desired outcome would be both fields are "technically" required. However, if a user types in their email address then both fields are now valid and vice versa if they fill out a phone number. Here is my code below.

HTML

```
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <label>Phone Number</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <input
                class="form-control"
                type="text"
                ngModel
                #contactPhone="ngModel"
                name="phone"
                minlength="10"
                [required]="contactEmail.invalid"
                (change)="checkValidation(name)"
              />
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Email</label>
              <input
                class="form-control"
                type="text"
                ngModel
                [ngClass]="setClasses(contactEmail, form)"
                #contactEmail="ngModel"
                name="email"
                maxlength="100"
                pattern="\b[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}\b"
                [required]="contactPhone.invalid"
                (change)="checkValidation(name)"
              />
            </div>
```

Relevant TS

```
  checkValidation(name) {
    if (
      this.form.controls[name]?.controls?.email?.value ||
      this.form.controls[name]?.controls?.phone?.value
    ) {
      this.eitherFieldRequired = false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in either one of two ways:

```
this.myFormGroup({ ... }, formValue => this.myValidator)
```

```
this.myFormGroup
  .get(‘myControl’)
  .valueChanges
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroyed), // handle the unsubscription
    tap(value => {
      if (value) {
        this.myFormGroup
          .get(‘myControl’)
          .setValidators([ ... ])
      } else {
        // unset validators
      }
    }),
  ).subscribe()
```

Let me know if you need more guidance.